# Manage Multiple Data sources in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, datasource, config

In my spring mvc application I need to connect to Multiple databases at a given time based on functionality selected by user in the front end. Let us say :

1.I have 3 different environments (PROD, PRE-PROD and Staging and more...)

2.User wants to see list of tables from the given database . User will select item from the select box and submits it. Based on user selection it needs to connect to respective database in and get results.

3.Some times some of the databases can go down and If I create JNDI data source for each database and map them to jdbcTemplate and all these jdbcTemplaates are defined as properties in my DAO like

```
<bean id="prodDataSource" ref="prodDSPool"/>
<bean id="preProdDataSource" ref="preProdDSPool"/>
<bean id="statgingDataSource" ref="stagingDSPool" />
...
...
```

And I have another bean which is nothing but my DAO

```
<bean id="myConnectionsDAO" class="com.example.MyConnectionsDAOImpl">
       <property name="prodDataSource">
             <ref bean="prodDataSource"/>
       </property>
       <property name="preProdDataSource">
             <ref bean="preProdDataSource"/>
       </property>
       <property name="preProdDataSource">
             <ref bean="preProdDataSource"/>
       </property>
</bean>
```

And MyConnectionDAO is a pojo with getter and setters for above properties.

As I said above depends on user selection my service class gets the associated datasource and builds the jdbcTemplate and queries the data base like

```
if(env.equalsIgnoreCase(EnvEnum.PROD.toString())
{
  JdbcTemplate prodTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(myConnectionsDAO.getProdDataSource());
prodTemplate.queryForList("select name form sysibm.systables where creator='admin');
//Core business logic to analyze those tables and proceed... 
}else if {//preprod logic} else if{//staging logic}
```

And I have lots of complex functionality which plays around data from DB2 database. Since I am injecting datasources are properties in to my dao using spring config; for any reason if one database/datasource is down I am not able to use my application and getting nullpointer since one or more data sources are down.

How can I handle these errors? Basically I want my app up and running if at least one ds is up. And I have around 50 Databases configured using above config.

I am pretty much confused and not getting a clue on how to solve this issue. 
Thanks in advance guys...

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will need to manage your own Spring Application Context per database.

That is you will start an application context as a child of your root [application context](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) for a given database. You will then have to manage the lifecycle of dynamic db/datasource application context going forward.

The other option is writing a custom single [Datasource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) that does this routing automagically behind the scenes. Which based on your edits looks like the best option.

```
public class RoutingDatasource implements DataSource, ApplicationContextAware {

    private volatile DataSource realDataSource;
    private ApplicationContext ac;

    // You must do some thread locking here that will be rather complicated.
    // That is not included in this example
    public void switchDatasource(String name) {
        this.realDataSource = this.ac.getBean(name, DataSource.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.ac = applicationContext;
    }

    // delegate to realDataSource


}
```

You will need to figure out how to safely lock the datasource object. I'll leave that for you (sorry ran out of time).

Comment: can you give me some code sample for the same. If I write a custom data source and If a need add support for more databases it will be cumbersome every time editing the classes right? Is spring provides any mechanism to handle the same out of the box?

Comment: You custom datasource is going to be spring aware. See ApplicationContextAware. You can probably come up with some naming scheming for the real datasources then your in your routing datasource you do something like applicationContext.getBean()....

Comment: Got you I have written my custom data source only for schema switching by implementing TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy but in some instances I need two or more different databases to perform some logic i.e get metadata from one db and validate values in other db. In that Case I will not be able to use RoutingDataSource solution. Thaks